# Angular: Keep all tabs as it is, when clicking on save

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web

I have 3 tabs with a common save button. One of the tabs has additional 3 tabs.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link nav-link"
                    [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 'Tab1'}"
                    (click)="selectedTab = 'Tab1'">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link nav-link"
                    [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 'Tab2'}"
                    (click)="selectedTab = 'Tab2'">Tab2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link nav-link"
                    [ngClass]="{'active': selectedTab === 'Tab3'}"
                    (click)="selectedTab = 'Tab3'">Tab3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I fill in some data on one of these tabs and click on save, it minimizes everything. And to view that saved data, I have to open everything again. The common save button looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group-sm mr-2" *ngIf="!readOnly">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

I would like to preserve the tab state when I click on save i.e. the page state before the save and after the save should be same. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Is the variable selectedTab reset in save option?

Comment: The save button stores the value of the high level tabs. These tabs are a part of one of those high-level tabs. So, their value is not being saved by that button.

Comment: I would rather see how `save()` looks alike

Comment: The save() method calls an API written in Java to save all of this information. Since, all the other tabs are working fine, I assume the bug lies on the angular side of things.